# How to get the latest record by joining 2 tbls?

Tags: yii

I've 2 tbls

customers

```
id | name | 
1  | aa   |
2  | bb   |
```

workorders

```
id | desc  | c_id (customer id) | created_date
1  | abcde | 1                  | 2013-11-18 01:00:00
2  | fghij | 1                  | 2013-11-19 10:00:00
3  | klmno | 2                  | 2013-11-19 11:00:00
```

I want the records as follow.

```
customer name | workorder_id | desc  | date
bb            | 3            | klmno | 2013-11-19 11:00:00
aa            | 2            | fghij | 2013-11-19 10:00:00
```

I want to add it into cgridview. How can I write CDbCriteria at yii frame work?

================================================================================

update

I found the query to get the latest record from workorders tbl as follow.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT c_id, wo_id, MAX(created_date) as MaxTime
      FROM workorders
      GROUP BY c_id) r
INNER JOIN workorders t ON t.c_id = r.c_id AND t.created_date = r.MaxTime
```

But I dont know how to join with customers tbl and create CDbCriteria. pls help me!!

==========================================================================================

last query (the correct one)

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM workorders t1
inner join customers t2 
    on t1.c_id = t2.id
inner join (SELECT MAX(workorders.created_date) maxts, c_id
            FROM workorders inner join customers
            ON workorders.c_id = customers.id
            GROUP BY c_id) t3
    on t2.id = t3.c_id and t1.created_date = t3.maxts
```

Comment: latest in which table?

Comment: I've 2 tbls (customers and workorders). the bottom one is which I want after join above 2 tbls (customers and workorders). and order by date DESC. How can I?

Answer (score 0):

if you have increamental primary keys, just use order by primary key column, decsending

```
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

if you're using criteria

```
$criteria->order = 'id DESC';
```

if command builder

```
 ->order->('id DESC');
```

or

->order->('date DESC');

I think something like this should do the trick:

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('c.name , w.id , w.desc , w.created_date as date')
->from('workorders w')
->join('customers c ' ,'w.c_id = c.id')
->order('w.date DESC')
->group('w.c_id')
->limit('10')
->queryAll()
```

Comment: I want to order by date DESC. and group by customer id

Comment: above query is retrieve the 1 and 3 of workorders tbl. Actual records should be 3 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not add foreign key to your workorders table, then first you need to add foreign key constraint.

**Query**

```
ALTER TABLE workorders ADD FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES customers(id)
```

Then by gii code generator, you create the model class for workorders and then create controller class.
If you do not have any idea about gii code generator, then below link is for you.

http://www.yiiframework.com/screencasts/

watch all videos to understand how yii works.

Then you have three different files.

- models/workorders.php
- controllers/WorkordersController.php
- Views/workorders/index.php

I have also created model for customers but i think there is no need for customers model, but if it gives error then you generate customers model too.
Now you should work start on your workorders controller file. and replace your actionIndex function code to below given code.

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
       $connection = Yii::app()->db;
       $sql        = "SELECT t1 . * , t2 . * FROM workorders t1 
            INNER JOIN customers t2 ON t1.c_id = t2.id
            INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MAX( workorders.date ) maxts, c_id
            FROM workorders
            INNER JOIN customers ON workorders.c_id = customers.id
            GROUP BY c_id
            )t3 ON t2.id = t3.c_id
            AND t1.date = t3.maxts";
            $command    = $connection->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
            $this->render('index', array('content' => $command));
    }
```

and write the below code in your view index file.

```
foreach($content as $cont=>$value) {
  echo $value['name']." ".$value['id'] ." ". $value['des'] ." ".$value['date'] ."<br>";
}
```

You get your required results.

Thanks